# Get last two params of an URL - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, url, split, slice

My URL looks like this

```
stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/format/return
```

I need to get only `format/return` from the above URL. I'm able to assign the complete URL to a variable. Currently i'm doing it on `split`

```
url.split("/")[4]
url.split("/")[5]
```

And this is not Generic. What is the better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortest, cleanest way to do this is by using [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) on the splitted URL:

```
url.split("/").slice(-2).join("/")
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the length to help you index from the end:

```
var res = url.split('/')
var last = res[res.length-1]
var pre_last = res[res.length-2]
```

Answer (score 1):

A genetic solution,

`Var URL = url.split("/");`   //

`Last = URL[URL.length-1];`    // return

`LastBefore = URL[URL.length-1];`    //format

```js
url = "stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/format/return"

URL = url.split("/"); 
console.log(URL[URL.length-1]) // return 
console.log(URL[URL.length-2]) //format
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for the last and penultimate values:

```
let spl = url.split("/");
alert(spl[spl.length-2]+' and '+spl[spl.length-1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd parse the url to a URL, then use match on the pathname. This way it will also work should you have any searchparams (`?foo=bar`) in your url

```js
const s = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/format/return";
const uri = new URL(s);
const m = uri.pathname.match(/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)$/);
console.log(m);
```

Note that you'll get an array holding three entries - 0 being the path combined, 1 the first and 2 the last param.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple **regex** `/.*\/(.*\/.*)/)` to extract exactly what you want.

```
str.match(/.*\/(.*\/.*)/).pop()
```

```js
var str = "stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/format/return",
  res = str.match(/.*\/(.*\/.*)/).pop();
  
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var parts = url.split("/");
lastTwo = [parts.pop(), parts.pop()].reverse().join("/");
```